# KQL - Convert Dynamic Array of Key Value to Key Value dictionary

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a cell of a table-column that is a dynamic. This was ingested from .Net as a Dictionary, but in Kusto it looks like an array of objects, that has a property key and value:

```
[
    {"key":"ProjectId","value":"1234"},
    {"key":"ProjectName","value":"Albatros"},
    {"key":"User","value":"Bond"}
]
```

I want to convert the contents of the cell in my Kusto query to the following dynamic:

```
{
  "ProjectId": "1234",
  "ProjectName": "Albatros",
  "User": "Bond"
}
```

I cant figure out how to write the expression, that converts it form the array into the new dynamic format.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Next time please prevent from doing updates like this and just open a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a combination of [`mv-apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator) and [`make_bag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-bag-aggfunction):

```
print d = dynamic([
  {"key": "value"},
  {"ProjectId": "1234"},
  {"ProjectName": "Albatros"},
  {"User": "Bond"}
])
| mv-apply d on (
    summarize result = make_bag(d)
)
```

| result |
| --- |
| { "key": "value", "ProjectId": "1234", "ProjectName": "Albatros", "User": "Bond" } |

**UPDATE** based on your change to the original question:

```
print d = dynamic([
    {"key":"ProjectId","value":"1234"},
    {"key":"ProjectName","value":"Albatros"},
    {"key":"User","value":"Bond"}
])
| mv-apply d on (
    summarize result = make_bag(pack(tostring(d.key), d.value))
)
```

| result |
| --- |
| { "ProjectId": "1234", "ProjectName": "Albatros", "User": "Bond" } |

Comment: Hi, Your answer was correct. But unfortunatly I discovered an error in my defined Input format. I updated the Question to the correct format, which contains Key/Value properties in the Array.

Comment: see **UPDATE** in the answer

Comment: Thanks @Yoni L. That did the trick :)